# Mongo query is not working for embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using `Spring Data Mongo` and simple mongo query to get the list of Active Status departments.

When I used below query, it still pulling the `InActive` records too.

```
db.getCollection('employee').find({"departments.status" : "A"})
```

Sample data -

```
{
    "firstName" : "Sichita",
    "lastName" : "Vinchurkar",
    "email" : "svinchurkar@gmail.com",
    "departments" : [ 
        {
            "deptName" : "IT Support",
            .......
            .......
            "status" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "deptName" : "Mobile Development",
            .......
            .......
            "status" : "I"
        }, 
        {
            "deptName" : "Advisory Dept",
            .......
            .......
            "status" : "A"
        },
        .........
        ..........
        .........
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using an aggregation with MongoDB Spring Data (v2.2.6) `MongoTemplate` API. You cannot retrieve specific array elements based a condition using a `find` query (so using the aggregation's `$filter` array operator).

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("departments.status").is("A")),
    project()
        .and(filter("departments")
                .as("dept")
                .by(Eq.valueOf("dept.status").equalToValue("A")))
    .as("departments")
);

AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "collection", Document.class);
results.forEach(doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```

[ EDIT ADD ]

Including the `import` statements for the classes and interfaces used in the code:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationResults;

import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.newAggregation;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.match;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.project;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators.Filter.filter;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ComparisonOperators.Eq;
```

Comment: How can we apply Pagination to get Employee data in the form of pagination?

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61608104/spring-data-mongo-perform-distinct-but-doesnt-pull-embedded-documents-in-res ?

Comment: What is filter here? Can you show import statements ?

Comment: `filter` is a _static_ method of the class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators.Filter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ArrayOperators.Filter.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('employee').find({"departments":{"status" : "A"}})
```