# MongoTemplate aggregation returns "IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference"

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

Given a collection with the following document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e8f83289d3a48132e9b6e34"
    },
    "resource-id": "my-default-network-map",
    "uri": "http://alto.example.com/networkmap",
    "mappings": [
       {
        "version-tag": "X",
        "address-aggregations": [{
            "pid": "PID1",
            "ipv4-addresses": ["192.0.2.0/24", "198.51.100.0/25"]
        }, {
            "pid": "PID2",
            "ipv4-addresses": ["198.51.100.128/25"]
        }, {
            "pid": "PID3",
            "ipv4-addresses": ["0.0.0.0/0"],
            "ipv6-addresses": ["::/0"]
        }]
       }, 
       {
        "version-tag": "Y",
        "address-aggregations": [{
            "pid": "PID1",
            "ipv4-addresses": ["192.0.2.0/24", "198.51.100.0/25"]
        }, {
            "pid": "PID2",
            "ipv4-addresses": ["198.51.100.128/25"]
        }]
       }],
    "_class": "com.example.restservice.entity.NetworkMapEntity"
}
```

and assuming more of these documents exist with other "resource-id" values, I wish that the same document i typed before gets returned, but the "mappings" array only contains the object with version-tag = X and the "address-aggregations" array only contains the objects with "pid" in [pidx,pidy,...]. The best i can currently come up with is the following aggregation pipeline:

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'resource-id': 'my-default-network-map'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$mappings'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'mappings.version-tag': 'X'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$mappings.address-aggregations'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'mappings.address-aggregations.pid': {
        '$in': [
          'PID1', 'PID2'
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id', 
      'resource-id': {
        '$first': '$resource-id'
      }, 
      'uri': {
        '$first': '$uri'
      }, 
      'version-tag': {
        '$first': '$mappings.version-tag'
      }, 
      'address-aggregations': {
        '$push': '$mappings.address-aggregations'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 1, 
      'resource-id': 1, 
      'uri': 1, 
      'mappings.version-tag': '$version-tag', 
      'mappings.address-aggregations': '$address-aggregations'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id', 
      'resource-id': {
        '$first': '$resource-id'
      }, 
      'uri': {
        '$first': '$uri'
      }, 
      'mappings': {
        '$push': '$mappings'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Which returned the expected result on the mongodb client shell. However, when i translate such object as a MongoTemplate query with an Aggregation object:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
  match(Criteria.where("resource-id").is(resourceId)),
  unwind("mappings"),
  match(Criteria.where("mappings.version-tag").is(versionTag)),
  unwind("mappings.address-aggregations"),
  match(Criteria.where("mappings.address-aggregations.pid").in(pids)),
  group("$_id")
    .first("resource-id").as("resource-id")
    .first("uri").as("uri")
    .first("mappings.version-tag").as("version-tag")
    .push("mappings.address-aggregations").as("address-aggregations"),
  project("_id", "resource-id", "uri")
    .and("version-tag").as("mappings.version-tag")
    .and("address-aggregations").as("mappings.address-aggregations"),
  group("_id")
    .first("resource-id").as("resource-id")
    .first("uri").as("uri")
    .push("mappings").as("mappings")
);


AggregationResults<NetworkMapEntity> aggregationResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "NetworkMaps", NetworkMapEntity.class);
```

and test it, the following exception is thrown: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference 'mappings'!`

Searching around I've found people with similar issues saying it was a bug with the springframework.data dependency, but on year old versions, so I think my construction of the Aggregation object may be the problem. Did I do something wrong in the Java code part of the solution?

Comment: To query and get specific sub-documents of an array you can use the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) aggregation operator.  A post which uses Spring Data MongoDB and `$filter`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989221/mongo-query-is-not-working-for-embedded-documents/60989911#60989911. Note that `$filter` lets you _iterate_ over an array of sub-documents and _filter_ the array based on a specified _condition_.

Answer (score 0):

Although I still don't understand why the current solution does not work and would like to understand why not, I changed the query as follows and it seems to work as intended now:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
  match(Criteria.where("resource-id").is(resourceId)),
  unwind("mappings"),
  match(Criteria.where("mappings.version-tag").is(versionTag)),
  unwind("mappings.address-aggregations"),
  match(Criteria.where("mappings.address-aggregations.pid").in(pids)),
  group("_id", "resource-id", "uri")
    .first("mappings.version-tag").as("version-tag")
    .push("mappings.address-aggregations").as("address-aggregations")
  group("_id._id")
    .first("_id.resource-id").as("resource-id")
    .push(
       new BasicDBObject("version-tag", "$version-tag")
             .append("address-aggregations", "$address-aggregations")).as("mappings")
);
```