# Spring Data Mongo - Perform Distinct, but doesn't wants to pull embedded documents in results

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm developing `Spring Boot and Spring Data Mongo` example. In this example, I want to get the distinct departments only, but I dont want to fecth subdepartments. What Query do I need to change?

```
db.employees.distinct("departments");
```

Data:

```
{
    "firstName" : "Laxmi",
    "lastName" : "Dekate",
    .....
    .......
    .....

    "departments" : {
        "deptCd" : "Tax",
        "deptName" : "Tax Handling Dept",
        "status" : "A",
        "subdepts" : [ 
            {
                "subdeptCd" : "1D",
                "subdeptName" : "Tax Clearning",
                "desc" : "",
                "status" : "A"
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: `db.collection.distinct` doesn't have the option of _projection_. You have to use Aggregation for that.

Comment: Could you please show me how can we do that ?

Comment: Correction. This code will get the distinct `deptCd`: `db.employees.distinct("departments.deptCd");`. The output would be: `[ "Tax" ]`.

Comment: Hey Prasad, actually I want whole deptCd, deptName, Status fields too

Comment: What is the distinct value you are looking for? Distinct `deptCd` ?

Comment: Even  `db.employyes.distinct("departments",  {}, {"subdepts": -1})` doesn't works

Comment: right, but with other fields as well

Comment: Distinct deptCd, but get the three fields cd, name and status. Thats an aggregation query.

Comment: Thats right and I need those fields as well

Comment: Can you share aggregate query ?

Comment: @prasad_ Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62260287/spring-data-mongo-how-to-get-the-nested-distinct-array-for-nested-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregation gets the distinct `departments.deptCd` values (plus other details):

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
{
    $group: { _id: "$departments.deptCd", 
             deptName: { $first: "$departments.deptName" },
             status: { $first: "$departments.status" }
    }
},
{
    $project: { deptCd: "$_id", _id: 0, deptName: 1, status: 1 }
}
] )
```

The output:

```
{ "deptName" : "Tax Handling Dept", "status" : "A", "deptCd" : "Tax" }
```

---

[ EDIT ADD ]

Code using Spring Data MongoDB v2.2.7:

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "testdb");
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.group("departments.deptCd")
        .first("departments.deptName").as("deptName")
        .first("departments.status").as("status"),
    Aggregation.project("deptName", "status")
        .and("_id").as("deptCd")
        .andExclude("_id")
);
AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "collection", Document.class);
results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks, how can we do Pagination here ?

Comment: What do you mean by pagination?

Comment: In spring data mongodb there is `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` interface and a repository `PagingAndSortingRepository`.

Comment: I am familiar with pagination, in general, not with Spring Data MongoDB APIs. The documentation says, Pageable and the PagingAndSortingRepository are used together. See [Repositories - Core concepts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts). There are examples too.

Comment: Can you share equivant of Spring Data Mongo please ?